# cannot implicitly convert type int to system.drawing.size

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is giving me the error "cannot implicitly convert type int to system.drawing.size"

```
myNumericUpDown.MinimumSize = 0;
```

Comment: -1 and voted for close. Have you checked what type `MinimumSize` wants? The error is very explicit about your issue...

Comment: @AlastairPitts Take it easy Bjarne Stroustrup, he is just learning! you could have explained to him nicely like the others did so he'll learn!

Comment: In general, when you see a Method returns a type or wants particular types as arguments to methods you need to give it what it expects...

Comment: @HaLaBi I understand that, but I find incredibly frustrating the apparent lack of desire from the OP to perform any self learning. A simple Google search, checking MSDN, checking IntelliSense or even a SO search would have provided enough information for the OP to determine their problem. It's lazy imo.

Comment: +1 I totally agree with @Alastair Pitts very well stated

Comment: @AlastairPitts You are right, but FYI, Google always leads to SE when it comes to coding questions, maybe he got mixed up and ended asking a question here.

Comment: @HaLaBi if he searches for "System.Drawing.Size" it leads to MSDN not SO. And for anyone with any experience coding in C# MSDN is the holy bible or quran or torah or bhagwad gita

Comment: Just a reminder, [Q: Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

Comment: Consider changing this to "how to assign Zero value to a struct type" if you really want to assign whatever zero is for given type...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx) is a struct with two integer properties. You could do `myNumericUpDown.MinimumSize = new Size(10,10);`.

Answer (score 4):

Size is defined as `Width` and `Height`, if you want to set `MinimumSize` you will have to declare a `Size` object and set the `Width` and `Height`

Example

```
myNumericUpDown.MinimumSize = new Size(0,0);
```

Or simply:

```
 myNumericUpDown.MinimumSize = Size.Empty
```

Comment: +1. `default(Size)` is another option (which matches intent of original post - "assign Zero (default) value".

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear what the compiler is complaining about.

The property is of type `System.Drawing.Size` and you are trying to use an `int`.

For example:

`myNumericUpDown.MinimumSize = new Size(2,4);`

MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`MinimumSize` is a property that gets `SIZE` class.

```
myNumericUpDown.MinimumSize = new Size(1,1)
```

- [UpDownBase.MinimumSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.updownbase.minimumsize.aspx)

But if you meant `Minimum` (*Gets or sets the minimum allowed value for the spin box*)

```
myNumericUpDown.Minimum = 1
```

- [NumericUpDown.Minimum Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.minimum.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Size` is a struct defined in `System.Drawing`

You cannot implicitly convert from `Size` to `int`.

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(SizeConverter))]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public struct Size
```

You probably meant `myNumbericUpDown.MinimumSize = new Size(1,1);`